# Python Pandas - Simple Row Count with Dates and Groupby Calculation

Tags: python, pandas

Here is an example of my problem. From an imported Excel sheet I have a list of names and years. I need to group the data by names and have a total for each year for each name. So for Bob I would have 2019 - 2, Adam 2019-1 and 2020-1, and Joe 2019-2 and 2020-1.I have been able to do this with a number of different groupby and pivot_table but I am unable to figure out how to do a calculation based on the date/year totals. I need to calculate the different in year's totals for Joe I need to have 2019 minus 2020 or -1. I am new to python and pandas. Any suggestions or help would be much appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_excel('c:/Users/home/Desktop/ABQ Lost.xlsx', usecols= ['Patient Full Name','Completed On', 'Dispensed Item Inventory Group', 'Facility Name'])
df['Patient Full Name']=df['Patient Full Name'].str.title()
df['year']=df['Completed On'].dt.year
year_table=pd.pivot_table(df, index = ['Patient Full Name'], columns=['year'],values = ['Completed On'], aggfunc = 'count', fill_value=0)

print (year_table.head(15))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Could you please post your code and an example of your data table? Thanks!

Comment: @DavideBrex - code has been posted. I am unable to post data table because it is patient healthcare information.

Comment: Could you post contrived data?  It doesn't need to be real but it should represent what the actual data looks like.

Comment: @DanielWalker - could not figure out how to post directly into "Body" so I used a clip. This is the output. I am not 100% sure if  this is what you are asking for or if you are asking to see the structure of the excel import data. Thank you for taking the time to review my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it in this way. 
Dummy dataframe to reproduce your situation:

```
import itertools as iter
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Patient":["Bob","Bob","Adam","Adam","Joe","Joe","Joe"],
    "Year":[2019, 2019, 2019,2020, 2019,2019,2020]
})
Patient   Year
0   Bob   2019
1   Bob   2019
2   Adam  2019
3   Adam  2020
4   Joe   2019
5   Joe   2019
6   Joe   2020
```

Create table with counts per year for each patient:

```
year_table=pd.pivot_table(df, index = ['Patient'],values = 'Year', columns="Year", aggfunc = len, fill_value=0)
year_table

Year    2019    2020
Patient     
Adam     1       1
Bob      2       0
Joe      2       1
```

Finally, compute the difference for each pair of years:

```
years_diff = pd.DataFrame(index=year_table.index)
for a, b in iter.combinations(year_table.columns, 2):
    years_diff['{}-{}'.format(a, b)] = year_table[a] - year_table[b]

        2019-2020
Patient 
Adam     0
Bob      2
Joe      1
```

Comment: worked perfectly. Thank you for taking the time to assist me. Have a great weekend.